# Modifying the WCF/REST or JSON help page

Tags: windows, rest, iis, soap

When a WCF/REST or JSON service is created in Visual Studio with helpEnabled="true" in the web config, there will be a URL similar to "https://Server/Service/ServiceREST.svc/**help**". IIS will present a help page - see enclosed example.

***I'm looking to modify this page, I want to exclude some lines.
Does anyone know how, or if that is possible?***

[image: SOAP/REST Help Example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, I would like to tell you that the help page of WCF WebHttp endpoint cannot be modified, and in fact there is no property or configuration to control it. You can replace it with your own custom page, but this requires writing a lot of code according to your needs. You can read about the schemas used in the WCF Web HTTP Services help page through this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/wcf-web-http-service-help-page).